# Flutter: StereamBuilder and Firebase RealTime

Tags: flutter

Hello I'am new in programming and aspecialy with flutter, i'm bulding a simple app to wrinte and read data from firebase database i have did a lot of research but i alawys have problems with syntax,
this is my data : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5khFi.png)

this is my code for reading data  :

```
final Database = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref('Users').child(UserId);


late DatabaseReference databaseReference;

 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    setState(() {});
  }

 StreamBuilder(
            stream: Database.orderByKey().onValue,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              final tilesList = <ListTile>[];
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                final myRobots = Map<dynamic, dynamic>.from((snapshot.data! as Event ).snapshot.value);
                myRobots.forEach((key, value) {
                  final nextRobot = Map<dynamic, dynamic>.from(value);
                  final RobotlTile = ListTile(
                      title: Text(nextRobot['Robot1']),
                      subtitle: Text(nextRobot['id']),
                  );
                  tilesList.add(RobotlTile);
                });
              }
              return Expanded(
                child: ListView(
                  children: tilesList,
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
```

But i have a problem (The getter 'snapshot' isn't defined for the type 'Event'.) with snapshot.value afte final myRobots

Answer (score 0):

See [this answer from another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53297378/streaming-data-from-firebase-realtime-database)

Comment: i made the change but stil have problem with  snapshot.data! :  (The argument type 'Object' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>')

Comment: See the edit I made